# Ambient Isotopy between punctured disc and annulus

Tags: general-topology

My professor defines an ambient isotopy between two A, B $\subseteq$ X as the following:

A function $h_t : [0,1] \times X \to X$ that satisfies i) for each $t \in [0,1]$, $h_t$ is a homeomorphism on $X$, ii) $h_0$ is the identity function on $X$, iii) and $h_1(A) = B$.

So if $A$ is a disc (with its boundary) minus its center, and $B$ an annulus (including its "outer" boundary, but not its inner boundary) with the same center in $\mathbb{R}^2$, can there be an ambient isotopy between $A$ and $B$?

My professor says it can be done and has provided an example, but I'm having trouble reconciling the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus B$, if it is indeed true.

Comment: Imagine putting your finger in the hole left by the center, and continuously pulling outward in a circular,uniform fashion, creating an annulus. Can  you see where the homeomorphism may come from now?

Comment: I understand the intuition, but $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ contains two disjoint sets, one being a singleton. What do we do with this singleton? That is, $A$ and $B$ are clearly homeomorphic, but the rest of the ambient space is perhaps not?

Comment: Of course the rest of the ambient space is, because while we were deforming $A$, $A^c$ was also getting simultaneously deformed, because it was expanding from the center of the annulus. Thus, even the complements remain homeomorphic.

Comment: But how does the singleton deform into a set with nonempty interior? Likewise, if we go backwards (from the annulus to the disc less its center), isn't it topologically "impermissible" to shrink something down to a point?

Comment: Why? Does homeomorphism have to preserve such a property? It doesn't have to preserve such a property at all.

Comment: Ok, say $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A$ and $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus B$ are homeomorphic. Let $a$ denote the center of the disc (the discussed singleton). Then $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus A \setminus \{a\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus B \setminus \{h_1(a)\}$, but using connected components as a topological invariant, this cannot be the case, correct?

Comment: I can see only one unbounded connected component in both. You are saying remove the center part of the annulus from $B$ and the center from $A$, right? Then only one unbounded connected component is left from each diagram.

Comment: Yes, but this is if the image of the center of $A$ under homeomorphism is indeed the entire center of the annulus $B$. But this cannot be the case, as there can be no surjection from a singleton to a non-singleton.

Comment: Ok. Finally I understand the problem. I think  I have run out of steam. You should ask your professor about this.